# "Multiple --up scripts defined" when running OpenVPN inside a Docker container

Tags: docker, openvpn, docker-compose

I'm using [binhex/arch-rtorrentvpn](https://github.com/binhex/arch-rtorrentvpn) and the contents of my `docker-compose.yml` are as follows:

```
version: "2"
services:
  rtorrent:
    image: binhex/arch-rtorrentvpn
    container_name: rtorrent
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
    environment:
      - VPN_ENABLED=yes
      - VPN_USER=<myusername>
      - VPN_PASS=<mypassword>
      - VPN_PROV=custom
      - VPN_OPTIONS=--script-security 2 --up /config/persists/tun_up.sh
      - VPN_CLIENT=openvpn
      - STRICT_PORT_FORWARD=no
      - ENABLE_AUTODL_IRSSI=yes
      - ENABLE_RPC2=yes
      - ENABLE_RPC2_AUTH=no
      - ENABLE_WEBUI_AUTH=no
      - LAN_NETWORK=192.168.1.0/24
      - NAME_SERVERS=1.1.1.1,1.0.0.1
      - DEBUG=true
      - PHP_TZ=Europe/London
      - UMASK=000
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
    volumes:
      - ./config:/config
      - ./downloads:/downloads
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    ports:
      - 9080:9080
      - 9443:9443
      - 8118:8118
    restart: unless-stopped
```

The issue I have is that, according to the [debug] output, my OpenVPN command line is as follows:

```
[debug] OpenVPN command line:- /usr/bin/openvpn 
--reneg-sec 0 
--mute-replay-warnings 
--auth-nocache 
--setenv VPN_PROV 'custom' 
--setenv VPN_CLIENT 'openvpn' 
--setenv DEBUG 'true' 
--setenv VPN_DEVICE_TYPE 'tun0' 
--setenv VPN_ENABLED 'yes' 
--setenv VPN_REMOTE_SERVER '213.152.188.3' 
--setenv APPLICATION 'rtorrent' 
--script-security 2 
--writepid /root/openvpn.pid 
--remap-usr1 SIGHUP 
--log-append /dev/stdout 
--pull-filter ignore 'up' 
--pull-filter ignore 'down' 
--pull-filter ignore 'route-ipv6' 
--pull-filter ignore 'ifconfig-ipv6' 
--pull-filter ignore 'tun-ipv6' 
--pull-filter ignore 'dhcp-option DNS6' 
--pull-filter ignore 'persist-tun' 
--pull-filter ignore 'reneg-sec' 
--up /root/openvpnup.sh 
--up-delay 
--up-restart 
--auth-user-pass credentials.conf 
--script-security 2 
--up /config/persists/tun_up.sh 
--cd /config/openvpn 
--config '/config/openvpn/nl910.nordvpn.com.tcp443.ovpn' 
--remote 213.152.188.3 443 tcp-client 
--remote-random
```

This throws the error: `Multiple --up scripts defined. The previously configured script is overridden` and the container will not start

I have tried calling the script by the below two methods, both of which resulted in the same error.

- Calling the `/root/openvpnup.sh` script via using the `;` separator. e.g.: `VPN_OPTIONS=--script-security 2 --up /config/persists/tun_up.sh;/root/openvpnup.sh`
- Calling the `/root/openvpnup.sh` script by adding `/root/openvpnup.sh` to the end of my `tun_up.sh` script.
- Running the script via other parameters (e.g.: `--tls-verify`) instead of `--up`

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion is that this is happening because you are defining the up script before the config. If you try to add running the **--up /config/persists/tun_up.sh** inside the ovpn config itself might work.

Another suggestion is to copy the script inside **/etc/openvpn** and not specify an absolute path to it.